# How to show setstate value when i click button each button like array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class ToggleClick extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            changeText :  "Welcome Zeeshan",    
            changeText1 : "Hello Zeeshan",  
            changeText2 : "Hello World" 
        }           
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); 
    }
    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.id;
    //alert(id);
    this.setState({ changeText: 'Hello Zeeshan' , changeText1 : "Hello Zeeshan 1" , changeText2 : "Hello Zeeshan 3" })
    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h2>Bind Event</h2>
                    <button id="btn1" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
                    <h4>{this.state.changeText}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ToggleClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous. So use callback.

```
this.setState({
  changeText: 'Hello Zeeshan' 
}, ()=>console.log(this.state.changeText))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but if you want to change the text on every click you could do it like that:

```js
class ToggleButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props)
    this.state = {
      textIndex: 0,
      texts: [
        'Hello Zeeshan 1',
        'Hello Zeeshan 2',
        'Hello Zeeshan 3'
      ]
    };
  }
  
  rotateText(){
    const { texts, textIndex } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      textIndex: textIndex < texts.length - 1
       ? textIndex + 1
        : 0
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { texts, textIndex } = this.state;
    return (
     <button onClick={() => this.rotateText()}>{texts[textIndex]}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Just add an array with string to state and count up a index(also in state). Then you only have to make the counter reset to 0 at the end of the array. Afterwards you can display the text by simply choosing the string from the array with the counter index.

Answer (score 0):

Remember **setState** is asynchronous, say you have your state as (in constructor)

```
this.state = {
   field1: value1, 
   field2: value 2
}
```

The sintax for setState is:

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

The appropriate way to use setState and having access to the current state on any event would be to use the 1st argument as an updater function like this (you don't need to use the second argument):

```
this.setState( (state) => {
   return {
    field1: somefunction(state)      // eg. state.field1 + state.field2
    field2: someOtherfunction(state) // eg. state.field2 + 1
   }
});
```

The value returned IS the new state that you want. In your particular case it would be something like in the constructor:

```
this.state = { 
 changeText: "Hello Zeeshan"
}
```

and on the click event you would have

```
this.setState((state)=> {
  let parts = state.changeText.split(" ");
  let text = parts[0];
  let counter = 0;
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    counter = parseInt(parts[1]);
  }

  let counter = extractCurrentCounter();
  return {
   changeText: text + ((counter > 0) ? " " + counter : "")
  }
})
```